# Website Integration with Facebook by using Facebook App

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk, iframe-app

I have created one Facebook App named "Digital Marketing" and I want to open my Website Page from Facebook app, I have given my Website URL in "Canvas Url" section of the App. After clicking on the App my Website is opening but I want to auto populate the fields (First Name, Last Name,Email) directly from Facebook (User logged in information) in my Website directly. 
The main goal is that the user will not have to enter his/her information again in my Website, it will come directly from Facebook. [It will prompt user to allow that his/her information will be shared------ If he/she "Allows" it------------ those public information (First Name, last Name,Email) will be populated dynamically in my Website page TextBox fields.

Comment: this [tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html) can help...

Answer (score 0):

use facebook oAuth ie) sign with facebook to get the details of the user who sign through the user.You get the necessary user details such as name,email,dob,etc.,

Comment: Thanks but user has already looged into Facebook. When user will click on the app--> Go to App button --> my Website page will open and user information will automatically displayed in my website. My website has been developed in ASP.net using C#